# Account Register, custom ID page created, access with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, customization

I want to create a system so a User can Signup / Login, and when they go on they are directed to a page of custom like blahurl.com/nations/customid, each ID is already generated when they sign up called UserID, and I want to be able to go blahurl.com/nations/92 and that person will pop up and their SQL info will be displayed.

I want so when they register they can already access these pages, I don't want to have to make a page for each person that signs up. How would I go about doing this? And then searching for them by their MySQL UserName?

- The table in my MySQL is called users
- The ID us called UserID
- The Username is called UserName
- The password is called Password
- The registration date is called RegDate

When people register they are automatically put to my submit-form.php which is this:

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['UserName'];
$password=$_POST['Password'];
$leadername=$_POST['LeaderName'];
$nationname=$_POST['NationName'];
$email=$_POST['Email'];

//Database connection
require_once("config.php");
require_once("checkregister.php");

//mysql query to insert value to database
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (UserName, Password, LeaderName, NationName, Email)
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$leadername', '$nationname', '$email')");
//if value inserted successyully disply success message
if($query)
{
    echo '<div style="color:#008000; font-weight:bold;">Your Account has been Created! <del>Check your Email for Verification Code!</del> in the future you will need to Verify your Account, for right now just <a href="../Login.php">go back to the Website!</a></div>';
} else
{
    //error message
    echo '<div style="color:#c24f00; font-weight:bold;">Registration Failed: Could not INSERT to Query! (Could not Connect to Database)<br><a href="../home.php">Back to Website</a></div>';
}

?>
```

- config.php connects to the Database
- checkregister.php checks to make sure that the Username / Leader Name
  does not yet exist and that no spaces are left empty.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to create anything?

Comment: @AlphaDelta Yes I just posted the code in an edit

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to have `http://yourwebsite/<id>` set up to a PHP script that will output the information of the user with the id of <id>?

Comment: Almost, I want it to pop up a custom page that will tell the information of that user with the ID, but that I can still put other content on there like Game Rules, and etc. I also don't want to have to create a new page for each new user manually, and if I can not do it auto, is there anyway to do this without creating a new page per user? Or is that impossible  But yes in that format for the URL (Actually I would prefer it to be http://yourwebsite/nations/<id>

Comment: Anyone who can solve this would definitely get a lot of Thanks, and a spot in the Game Credits, This is a Core Feature of the game, so it's very important to me, all help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: You posted code using mysql (deprecated) and subject to SQL injection attacks.  Seems like you have some other problems you need to work out.

Comment: @Devon What do you mean? Also if we could stay on topic, if you mean that I posted the values of the MySQL Code, I do have a small protection against Injection in the checkregister.php also I could change em if need be.... Srsly anyone got an answer? This is a core function and I have yet to figure it out

Comment: You should research SQL injections if you don't know what I'm talking about.  Quite possibly the most common security issue on the web.  NEVER use user input directly in a SQL query.  "Small protection" probably isn't enough, there is no reason to use mysql_ and not used prepared statements these days.

Comment: @Devon Good to know, but please if we can resolve this issue first? I really need this as it is a Core Feature of the game

Comment: @BlakeGillman, thats the reason I downvoted this.  I'm not going to assist anyone who has security issues in their code.  Especially when they consider it low priority.  Remove your question, research SQL injections and prepared statements using mysqli or PDO, fix the security concerns, then re-ask your question.

Comment: @Devon I don't at all, Infact I am looking at this right now https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet I just think that in the meantime well I am working with that, I could get some answers on how to do what I asked.

Comment: To add some more research, what you want isn't coding as much as it is configuration.  You need to use mod_rewrite (or a similar web server extension) to forward nation/<id> to something like nation.php?id=<id>

Comment: @Devon I am fairly new to PHP and MySQL, used to 3D Game Dev with Game Engines, not browser based, Could you explain a little further? (Explain it in very easy to understand terms please xD)

Comment: mod_rewrite is an extension for Apache.  You can use it to alter the url, as per your requirement.  Using the correct syntax in the web server configuration (or htaccess file) you can direct requests from nation/id to a php file.

Comment: @Devon I dont mean to sound stupid, but what is Apache?

Comment: To add to Devon's comments, you need to ensure your passwords are not stored in plain text too - they need to be strongly hashed and salted. Have a look at php.net/password_hash. Inadequate hashing was the reason the attack on Sony's console network was so serious - and plain text is worse.

Comment: Apache is the name of the web server software you are likely running.

Comment: @halfer Alright, can anyone give me some examples / a bit further help with this whole mod_rewrite thing? I am having a lot of trouble understanding it

Comment: @BlakeGillman. It seems like you need to take to Google and do some real research.  You have a lot to learn before putting a public app on the web.

Comment: I wonder whether `mod_rewrite` is extra complexity at this stage that you don't need - can you just use `blahurl.com/nations?customid=123` for now? That way you can just use a single script and read the `customid` from it easily. If you really do want pretty URLs, there are [plenty of examples here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mod_rewrite+php).

Comment: @halfer How would I go about that customid way? (In the SQL Database it's called UserID) Because I don't need fancy URL's right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked how to link to a non-fancy URL, which is fairly easy. You just need to get the primary key, which will have been created from your auto-increment column:

submit-form.php

```
// Create user
// @todo Fix injection vuln
$query=mysql_query( ... );

// If successful...
if($query)
{
    // Get the inserted primary key
    $userId = mysql_insert_id();
    ?>
    <div style="color:#008000; font-weight:bold;">
        Your account has been created,
        <a
            href="nations.php?userId=<?php echo $userId ?>"
        >go back to the website!</a>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

You can then read it in the other page:

nations.php

```
<?php
// Read it only if it exists
$userId = isset($_GET['userId']) ? $_GET['userId'] : null;

// Escape any apostrophes in the ID, to avoid SQL injection
$cleanUserId = mysql_real_escape_string($userId);

// Always check if it exists, the user may have tampered with the URL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID = '$cleanUserId'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
// Do something with the result...
```

Some general notes now follow. These are probably too much to absorb in one go, but if you do some reading around them, they will help in the long term:

- When you do a POST operation, you should generally follow it up with a redirect, unless it has failed (and you need to render validation/error messages). This is because browsers don't like to render content in a post method, and if you then refresh the screen, browsers will ask you to confirm if you wish to re-submit the operation. In most cases you do not, since it will repeat what happened in the post (in this case, creating a user)
- To carry information over a POST-redirect, often the session is used. Some frameworks offer "flash messages", which are just session values that are cleared after one page view. Alternatively the query string can be used. Either way, this would be useful to carry your user ID from the post page to a result page, so that refreshing the screen does not result in re-submission.
- Logic and presentation is intermingled here, which will make for an app that is rather hard to maintain. When you get chance, try to move all your logic (e.g. database calls) to the top of the page, and put your presentation HTML at the bottom of the script. Tiny pieces of PHP can be used where dynamic content is required.
- You may find using a web framework helpful to give further structure and modularity to your code. There is no "best" PHP framework, so choose from Slim, Laravel, Aura, Symfony, Zend, Cake, CodeIgniter, and several others. It's worth trying a few to see what you prefer.
- Swap to a newer database library - the `mysql_` calls are no longer maintained. They will throw notices in PHP 5.5+.
- As per the comments, use parameter binding and password hashing for security. Don't go live until these are both fixed.
- If you are not using version control, it's worth getting into the habit. Git is pretty simple to use, and integrates automatically with a number of IDE applications (e.g. NetBeans).

Comment: There's a lot to take in here. I have a free tutorial/book on the web that deals with much of this correctly, and it would be helpful to your stage of learning. See my Stack Overflow profile if it is of interest.